# Parsing XML to CSV or YAML - Error "CData section not finished"

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

I'm trying to parse data collected from a Checkpoint firewall which is in XML format. Ideally, I would like XML data converted to csv or xml format. Once I'm there then I'm good.

Top of XML Text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../network_objects.xsl"?>
```

Code I'm trying, this code I got from other posts.

```
from lxml import etree
file = "network_objects.xml"
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding = "iso-8859-1")
tree = etree.parse(file, parser)
```

Error I'm getting. I don't know anything about XML and what CData is. Can someone provide some guidance?

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: CData section not finished
Petroleum Traders public tunnel IPë½¨Äë»¼, line 6787, column 651
```

Comment: You need to show us more than "Top of XML text". Here is an explanation of CDATA sections: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML

Comment: I went and found that block of text "Petroleum Traders public tunnel IPë½¨Äë»¼," from the file and removed it with a text editor. This fixed my issue. It looks like a lot of special characters was breaking the parse. It would be useful to automatically skip these rather than manually removing them.if anyone out there can help.

Comment: Share the input (valid xml file) and the requested output.

Comment: Syntax errors are serious. There isn't really any way to just automatically skip the problematic parts of an XML document.

Comment: Could be a encoding issue, too. If I check this characters with `charset_normalizer` it tells it's cp864 = IPﺽﺵﺎﺅﺽ؛ﺱ<.